# wxpython fixed frame size?

Tags: python, wxpython, frame

Is it possible to create a frame with a fixed size, so the user can not change the size of the frame ?

```
wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Hello',wx.DefaultPosition,(400, 300))
```

I'm using `python 2.7`

thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible -

```
wx.Frame.__init__(None, -1, 'Title', style= wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX)
```

Comment: You can see other frame styles here - http://zetcode.com/wxpython/firststeps/#frame

Comment: @nmnm - If you the answer useful you can upvote and accept it

Comment: @Guanidene Could you please describe exactly which of those styles actually makes the window not resizable?!?!

Comment: @Radu as far as I remember, I am just specifying wx.CLOSE_BOX, no minimize and maximise boxes. This perhaps makes it non resizable.
(I don't use wxpython anymore. I have shifted to PyQt4. Would like to recommend you the same)

Comment: @Guanidene why did you switch to PyQt4 and why do you recommend it?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to remove the RESIZE_BORDER flag from the Frames 
style bitmask but keep the default frame style. You'll want to disable the maximize box too.

i.e)

style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SetSizeHints to control how big or how small you want to resize it or not resize the frame at all.